# Get recyclerView item from possition

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm creating a app that contains a recycler view, and the user adds any number of items he wants. Is there a way to get one of these items in any activity according to its position?

On BindViewHolder in adapter:

```
holder.tvName.setText(list.get(possition).getName);
holder.tvNumber.setText(list.get(possition).getNumber);
```

Suppose that the list contain 10    items, and I want to get the name in possition three from the list

How I can do it?

I try to get the value without possition and it gets the last value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply define a static field(variable) for item's list. and write a static method in your adapter that takes a position and returns an item by position.
note that at first you must initialize the static variable by your list in the adapter.

For example:

```
private static list ArrayList<Item>;
...
//write the below code in the adapter. you can write it in constructor or write it in a setter method that you will write or any else where!
list = // assign your items list to this variable (initializing and assigning)
...
public static Item getItemByPosition(int position){
        return list.get(position);
}
```

use it like below in any activity:

```
Item myItem = YourAdapter.getItemByPosition(3);
String myName = myItem.getName();
```